# Android Studio Not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know this is duplicate question as I followed all the solutions but dint got my problem resolved.

Am using 64bit windows 7 os with 64bit java.

Currently am using eclipse for android development which works fine.

But when I tried to install android studio, as soon as I click next It is crashing with this details.

[image: Android studio crashing like this]

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: android-studio-bundle-130.737825-windows.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4b1ae3cc
  Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17725
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ec49b8f
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00033e2d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

The solutions which I tried are

Checking my path and JAVA_HOME and it is correct.
I added ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK with this my java path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

I restarted but still same problem, I dont want to install 32bit java and check as my eclipse and java are 64bit I dnt want to disturb it.

Am also using netbeans with this java and everything works fine except this studio.

What can be the problem please assist me.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating JDK. Also try running the install as Administrator.

Edit :

It seems something is up with the **ntdll.dll** try searching for fixes Android Studio Installer is not the only one experiencing these problems.

Comment: my jdk is upto date and I tried as Administrator but still same. I googled for ntdll.dll and also used some dll repair s/w's but still no use.